# LibreOffice Caption with page breaks?

Tags: libreoffice-writer, caption

When I create a writer document with a rather large image, and then add a longish caption to the image, the caption is either cropped or runs over the footer.
I'd prefer it to treat it more like normal text and just "reflow" the bit that is too much to the next page. Is that possible?

Comment: If the caption of one image is too long / too close to the end of the page, I'd like it to continue on the next page.

Comment: To make it clear, we are talking about the writer and about the page caption, right?

Comment: We are talking about the writer, but about image caption, i.e. select the image you want to add a caption to, go to Insert->Caption. This way you also get automatic numbering, e.g. Figure 5: […]

Comment: yeah, I guessed I'm missing something, sorry. Never dealt with image captions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could put the image and its caption into a singe-column table (two rows, first for pic, second for caption). This way, LO can insert a page break into the caption cell. Maybe even a 1x1 table will work - see also [this OOo forum thread](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=31427&start=0).